# Can Kafka 10 kafka-consumer-groups.sh describe a single topic's offsets for a given group?

Tags: apache-kafka

Why can't I get queue depth checks for a specific topic any more? The old ConsumerOffsetChecker via runClass used to let me.

Did someone overlook allowing --topic when you are asking for --describe?

I don't want everything in the whole group (which covers 12 different topics). I don't want to have to grep out the topic I want (wasting time returning all the topics just so I can get info on one of them), and I definitely do not want to make a separate group for every topic; they all work a a single logical cursor state checkpoint pipeline in my mind.

Am I amiss here? Isn't this removing functionality from previous releases?

Here is what doesn't work, that I believe should:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group test-group --topic test-topic --describe
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right. There are a couple of functionalities in ConsumerOffsetChecker that are still missing in ConsumerGroupCommand (as of version 0.11.0.0). They will be added in the future, but in the meantime, probably grepping the output will be the best choice for you.